# Is there anyway to divide account tweets using API into categories for news?

Tags: twitter-api

I'm planning to create a news website using twitter API to fetch tweets of specific news resource accounts. Is there anyway to categorize them into sports, break news, culture ... etc?

Here's the example of sample timeline result

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline